# doxyrest command returns "duplicate member id group..."

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, doxygen, restructuredtext, documentation-generation

I'm generating documentation for my code using `doxygen`, `doxyrest` and `sphinx-build` commands.

No warnings while using `doxygen Doxyfile`, but when I type in `doxyrest -c doxyrest-config.lua` to generate rst, based on the xml made by Doxygen, my screen gets full of errors like this one:

> warning: duplicate member id group___my_example_group_commands_1gaaa56d9b... (function: ExampleFunction)

I'm using `\addtogroup` to group more functions at a time, like this:

```
/** \addtogroup MyGroup
* @{ */

   /** \addtogroup SomeSubgroup
   * @{ */

      void someFunctionHere(int param1, int param2, ...) {
         ... // some stuff here
      }
      
      void someOtherFunction(char *param1, ...) {
         ... // some other stuff here
      }

   /** @} */

/** @} */
```

My question is: where does that `duplicate member id ...` error come from? Do you have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: which versions of the different packages are you using?

Comment: @albert doxygen 1.9.2, doxyrest 2.1.2 and sphinx 3.5.4

Comment: With the scarce information present I can reproduce the problem in doxygen, probably best is to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker with just a small case and the `GENERATE_XML` enabled as in my case I see the problem in the combination `aa_8h.xml` and `group___some_subgroup.xml`, in the HTML and LaTeX output the problem is not present.

Comment: An issue has been filed: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8790